# Как заставить работать .htaccess в Apache 2.4 (mod_rewrite)?

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess, apache

Обновил Apache до версии 2.4, перестал работать mod_rewrite. Что нужно изменить в файле, чтобы он стал работать с новой версией апача?

Сам файл .htaccess:

> AddDefaultCharset utf-8
>
> php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
>
> php_value post_max_size 50M
>
> php_value max_execution_time 10800
>
> php_value max_input_time 10800
>
> php_value date.timezone UTC
>
> DirectoryIndex index.php
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> Options -ExecCGI -Indexes -Includes +FollowSymlinks
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]

В последних строчках - идет перенаправление на индексный файл, который и делает полный разбор URL'а. Ранее эта конфигурация прекрасно работала на разных системах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось все просто, в директории сайта прописываем:

`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
AllowOverride All`

Сам файл htaccess менять не нужно